# How do I log or monitor JMS messages placed on a queue?

Tags: jboss6.x, hornetq

We are on JBoss EAP 6.4.

There is a JMS queue that has a consumer who immediately consumes everything that is placed to the queue.

I want to check what is placed to the queue but for my tool (Hermes JMS) the queue is always empty.

I tried configuring fine level logging for "org.hornetq" category but messages placed to the queue are not logged at any debug level.

Is there a way to see what is placed to the queue when it is immediately consumed?

Thanks,

Valery

Comment: Are you wanting to see the *content* of the message or just the fact that a message was put on the queue?

Comment: Actually I need the content, but if this is not possible just the fact that massage was placed is still good.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to see the content but only see the flow, you could execute read-resource command, or create a custom script that reads the queue and certain times and calculate the flow. You would just need to parse it and calculate, doing your own tool, simple and efficient.

CLI command to read jms queue

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=testQueue/:read-resource(recursive=false,proxies=false,include-runtime=true,include-defaults=true)
```

[Reference for CLI](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/monitoring-jms-resources-with-jboss-as-7)